# How can I expand asp.net identity registration with info from another table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have a table `Food` and I want to show all information from that table when the user register in `Account/register.cshtml`. I have tested to add this in `AccountController`

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var food = db.Food.Select(x => x.Food).ToList();
    return View(food);
}
```

My view register.chhtml looks like this

```
@model FoodApplication.Models.RegisterViewModel
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{ 
    @item.Food    
}
```

Get an error that I can't use foreach in view model.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good approach, because of changing default AccountViewModel, but you will achive the desired result

Change the AccountViewModel

```
public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

        public List<Food> Products = null;
    }
```

Change Index method in AccountController

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new RegisterViewModel()
        {
            Products = db.Food.Select(x => x.Food).ToList()
        });
    }
```

Add to Register.cshtml

```
<ul>

    @foreach (var z in Model.Products)
    {

        <li>@z.id</li>
        <li>@z.name</li>    
    }

</ul>
```

Comment: Should I not update controller "public ActionResult Register()" instead of index? And I get this error in the controller "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Project.Models.Products>'"

Comment: 1 yes you are right, change Register 2 And check the types here `Products = db.Food.Select(x => x.Food).ToList()`